# Block all EU visitors due to GDPR

Tags: php, http, http-headers, ip-address, privacy

GDPR imposes million-dollar fines for who-knows-what infractions, which is insane. Is there a simple no-cost solution in PHP to dealing with it for my personal website? I don't *need* to track people but I'd like to at least have some idea who's visiting e.g.  I want to know browser, OS, organization. I am certainly open to blocking all EU visitors *but* I know many set their browser to English, so blocking by language is ineffective.

As a non-lawyer and a maintainer of just a simple website that makes no money, I recognize that I'll never fully understand the GDPR and I'll never have the funds to keep up to date on it as it changes. Only large companies can even afford to spend the required amount of time, effort and money. So I need a simple mechanism to block EU users or else, I'll have to take a conservative approach of either collecting no data on visitors.

This GDPR law threatens people with economic death for non-compliance, but the vast majority of people have no idea what its vague rules really require. It's a law that favors big companies with resources and is an attack on small companies and individuals.

Comment: GDPR is not limited to the EU. It applied to anybody doing business in or with the EU

Comment: Personal websites are affected. if you have a blog and you record IP addresses, that's illegal now.

Comment: I really think you have to actually understand GDPR rather than attempt to disaccociate yourself

Comment: There is no fool-proof way of doing that. IPs can be spoofed, or you can use a VPN. The language set on the browser may not be a user from Europe, even though they use a European language. Spanish is a language spoken in many countries, not just Spain.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No one can fully understand GDPR without a team of lawyers.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not exactly. It's supposed to protect citizens of EU countries - it doesn't mean that a US corporation that decides to comply with GDPR needs to apply the rules to citizens from non-EU countries. However, there's pretty much no practical way of discerning visitors by "EU allegiance", so in the end, if you abide by the law at all (whether or not you're *required* to), applying it to all visitors/customers is the simpler option. Especially if we're talking about multi-national corporations :)

Comment: @Qirel Not to mention that just because I'm visiting the US doesn't mean the law no longer considers me a citizen of an EU country. The sad thing is, even if you act in good faith and discriminate based on nationality, someone who *lies* about their nationality (and says they're not from an EU country, but actually is), you still have to comply with most of the requests that GDPR requires you to. I've read the whole thing many times through and through, and it seems they didn't even consider that someone might abuse this law :/ Presumably, we'll get a harsher follow-up law for that...

Comment: Try [cookieyes](https://www.cookieyes.com) free GDPR solution for any platform

Answer (score 10):

First of all, it's probably best to read about legitimate interests first -- https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/legitimate-interests/when-can-we-rely-on-legitimate-interests/ -- then ask what's your legal basis for collecting personal data from users?

Related to your question, there's actually a possibility via nginx and GeoIP database.

Install the GeoIP Database for nginx:

```
apt-get install geoip-database-contrib -y
```

Update your nginx configuration (outside the `server {} block`):

```
# Block the EU continent from accessing the site

geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
geoip_city /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat;
map $geoip_city_continent_code $allow_visit {
   default 1;
   EU 0;
}
```

Inside your `server {}` block, disable logging of EU users and return 403:

```
# Disable logging for EU users
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$allow_visit;
# Block and return 403 error message to EU users
default_type text/plain;
if ($allow_visit = 0) {
        return 403 'You are prohibited from visiting this website due to GDPR compliance requirements.';
    }
```

Restart nginx

```
service nginx restart
```

Credits to https://medium.com/@jacksonpalmer/gdpr-for-side-projects-blocking-all-eu-traffic-with-nginx-in-3-simple-steps-136ddd8078a4

Comment: The OP states they have a very simple website, so I would assume that this is being hosted on a virtual-shared server. This means that the OP would not be able to deploy this on his small site, as he would not have access to the server logs outside of a read-only mode.

Answer (score 1):

For those not confident, or not able to access and modify server configurations, there is a simple plugin available for this also which may be much easier for many people to implement. You just add a JavaScript tag to the opening  tag in your page(s) code, according to the install instructions provided on the site.

https://www.ezigdpr.com/products/eu-visitor-blocker

By firing the blocking script at the first instance of a page load, it prevents any tracking scripts, plugins or pixels from loading.

If you have the technical ability and access, you can then also consider turning off IP logging at the server level; though it is arguable that if you don't know how to access this, then it may not be in scope of GDPR.

You may also want to read the following blog article, which outlines the different considerations and compliance pitfalls relating to blocking EU traffic.

https://www.ezigdpr.com/blog/2018/06/05/6/is-it-gdpr-compliant-to-block-eu-visitors

Answer (score 1):

MaxMind has APIs for detecting the country in just about every programming language. They are also modules for Apache, Varnish, and Nginx. If you want to go more granular with detecting the correct city, then you have to pay, otherwise, it's all free.

See https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/#MaxMind_APIs

And since this question was specifically about PHP, you can Block EU countries in PHP by first installing the composer package:

`php composer.phar require geoip2/geoip2:~2.0`

And then using it like so

```
const EU_COUNTRY_CODES = [
   'AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DK', 'EE', 'FI', 'FR', 'DE', 'GR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IT',
   'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'MT', 'NL', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SK', 'SI', 'ES', 'SE', 'GB'
];

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

$reader = new Reader('/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-City.mmdb');

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// If you're behind a reverse proxy, you may need to do
// $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
// or whatever IP address header your proxy sets when forwarding the request

$record = $reader->country($ip);

if (in_array($record->country->isoCode, EU_COUNTRY_CODES), true){
    echo "We detected you where connecting from ";
    echo $record->country->name;
    echo ". We do not currently allow connections from the EU";
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the EU GDPR, remember that the legal jurisdiction of the court will be that stated in your websites own 'Terms of Use' agreement (or should be the case anyway). What is important in the law is that the website owner has made a 'good-faith effort' to ban the website from those member countries.

Given that, below is a re-usable PHP function that uses 'ip-api.com' API to return location data on an IP and check it against a white-list of current EU member countries. The white-list is easy to maintain, which is good, as countries entering and leaving the EU are in a continual flux. The white-list was put together on July 24, 1018 with the data crossed-checked between the EU official website and Wikipedia. The 'ip-api.com' API is free for personal use (contact for commercial use), and can be run from your local server as well, and without registration or domain requirement.

```
function inEU($ip_input){

  // Validate the IP address
  if (filter_var($ip_input, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === false){
    // Not a valid IP address - build error response
    $message_string =
      '<div style="width:100%; margin-top:50px; text-align:center;">'.
        '<div style="width:100%; font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-size:24px; color:#c00; centered">'.
          'ERROR:&nbsp;<span style="color:#fd0">Invalid IP Address</span>'.
        '</div>'.
      '</div>';
    echo $message_string;
    exit;
  }

  // Array of country names and country codes of European Union member countries
  $eu_members = array(
    'Austria','AT',   'Belgium','BE',      'Bulgaria','BG',
    'Croatia','HR',   'Cyprus','CY',       'Czech Republic','CZ',
    'Denmark','DK',   'Estonia','EE',      'Finland','FI',
    'France','FR',    'Germany','DE',      'Greece','GR',
    'Hungary','HU',   'Ireland','IE',      'Italy','IT',
    'Latvia','LV',    'Lithuania','LT',    'Luxembourg','LU',
    'Malta','MT',     'Netherlands','NL',  'Netherlands Antilles','AN',
    'Poland','PL',    'Portugal','PT',     'Romania','RO',
    'Slovakia','SK',  'Slovenia','SI',     'Spain','ES',
    'Sweden','SE',    'United Kingdom','GB','UK'
  );
  $query_url = 'http://ip-api.com/json/'.$ip_input;  // Build query URL for IP to JSON Data request
  $ip_data_fetched = file_get_contents($query_url);  // Return IP Data JSON as a string
  $ip_data_fetched = utf8_encode($ip_data_fetched);  // Encode returned JSON string to utf-8 if needed
  $ip_data         = json_decode($ip_data_fetched);  // Decode utf-8 JSON string as PHP object

  // Get the Country and Country Code for the IP from the returned data
  $country     = $ip_data->country;      // Country Name (i.e; 'United States')
  $countryCode = $ip_data->countryCode;  // Country Code (i.e; 'US')

  // Check the EU members array for match to either country or country code
  $in_EU = false;                        // Ref for function boolean value returned - set false
  $num_members = count($eu_members);     // Number of indexes in EU members array (not # of members)
  for ($i = 0; $i < $num_members; $i++){
    $lc_eu_members = strtolower($eu_members[$i]);
    if ($lc_eu_members === strtolower($country) || $lc_eu_members === strtolower($countryCode)){
      $in_EU = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return $in_EU;
}
```

And to use the function...

```
if (inEU( $ip )){
  // IP address IS in an EU country
}
else {
  // IP address IS NOT in an EU country
}
```

The function also cross-checks the returned location data in the same loop, so if there was a typo in one var, it would still find the location using the other var. For both to be wrong is not likely.

This function can easily be adapted to work with many other IP to location API's that return a JSON response. It can also be easily be adapted as an 'allow only' white-list, rather than 'ban' white-list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I use `websiteip2location.com`, which is a website that purports to list all IP addresses. IP Deny Manager is a utility available with most hosting services that use C-Panel.

While it may seem meticulous, I intend to copy every ip address range for every country in the EU and paste it in the IP Deny Manager tool from C-Panel.

I'm not sure if this is the best technical solution for this, but it's the best that I could come up with.

Comment: Does anyone know how frequently these IP address country ranges change. They couldn't possibly stay the same forever.

Comment: @hostingutilities.com Most are relatively static, but they can change at any time. I have noticed a couple in the last 2 months and I'm only looking at ones that are actively attacking sites I maintain. That said...it's not reliable. I had to create exceptions for a "Netherlands" address hosted by Datacamp in Texas (which in turn was hosting a legitimate VPN) recently. (Not the now-gone site listed above, though, but same underlying tables.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IP2Location PHP Module](https://www.ip2location.com/development-libraries/ip2location/php) along with the free IP2Location LITE DB1 database.

Download the BIN database file from https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country and extract the BIN file out.

**Installation**

Add the below line into your composer.json file.

```
{
  "require": {
    "ip2location/ip2location-php": "8.*"
  }
}
```

Run the command:

```
composer install
```

**PHP code**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

$EEA_COUNTRIES = [
    'AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DK', 'EE', 'FI', 'FR', 'DE', 'GR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IS',
    'IT', 'LI', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'MT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SK', 'SI', 'ES', 'SE'
];

$db = new \IP2Location\Database('./database/IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.BIN', \IP2Location\Database::FILE_IO);

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$records = $db->lookup($ip, \IP2Location\Database::ALL);

if (in_array($records['countryCode'], $EEA_COUNTRIES)) {
    die('You are coming from ' . $records['countryName'] . ' which is part of the European Economic Area.<br />Visitors from the EU/EEA are not allowed access to this website due to GDPR.');
}
```

Comment: 'NO' is missing. We are not in EU but have adapted this crazy GDPR directive.

Comment: Have added the 3 non-EU countries that are part of the EEA.